# Angular JS Directive loaded in expression

Tags: angularjs, angular2-directives

I'm new to Angular, and have found a ton of resources about directives and nesting, but can't seem to get this simple example to work. So basically I am working on a tabset, I have an HTML template:

`tabset.html`

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="tab in tabset.tabs" ng-class="{active:tabset.current()==$index}">
            <a href ng-click="tabset.current($index)">{{tab}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div>
        <div ng-repeat="pane in tabset.panes">
            <div ng-show="tabset.current()==$index">
                {{pane.contents}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And a search form template:

`search-form.html`

```
<div>
    <form name="ytSearch" ng-submit="YTCtrl.submit()" novalidate>
        <label for="search_box">Search For: </label>
        <input id="search_box" ng-model="YTCtrl.searchString"/>
        <br>
        <label for="location">Location: </label>
        <input id="location" ng-model="YTCtrl.location"/>
        within
        <input type="numeric" value="100" ng-model="YTCtrl.locationRadius" />
        <select ng-model="YTCtrl.locationUnit">
            <option value="ft">Feet</option>
            <option value="m">Meters</option>
            <option value="mi">Miles</option>
            <option value="km">Kilometers</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <label for="search_order">Sort By: </label>
        <select id="search_order" ng-model="YTCtrl.order">
            <option value="relevance">Relevance</option>
            <option value="date">Date</option>
            <option value="rating">Rating</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <button id="search">
            Search
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

And a simple app file with 2 directives to handle each of the templates:

`app.js`

```
(function() {
    angular.module("JHYT", [])
        .directive("sidebarTabset", function($compile) {
            return {
                restrict : 'E',
                templateUrl : 'tabset.html',
                controller : function($scope, $compile, $http) {
                    this._current = 0;
                    this.current = function(i) {
                        if (i != null)
                            this._current = i;
                        return this._current;
                    };
                    this.tabs = ['Search', 'Favorite'];
                    this.panes = [{
                        contents : "<search-form></search-form>"
                    }, {
                        contents : "Favorite Pane"
                    }];
                },
                controllerAs : 'tabset',
            };
        }).
        directive("searchForm", function() {
            return {
                restrict : 'E',
                templateUrl : 'search-form.html',
                controller : function($scope, $compile, $http) {
                    this.searchString = '';
                    this.location = '';
                    this.locationRadius = '';
                    this.locationUnit = 'mi';
                    this.order = 'relevance';
                    this.submit = function() {
                        console.log("Submit");
                    };
                },
                controllerAs : 'YTCtrl',
            }
        });
})();
```

So as you can probably tell, the idea is to be able to send a JSON object into the tabset (through a service probably) and have it build out a dynamic tabset, that actually works exactly as I expected it to. What isn't working is that in the first tab, the content, which is `<search-form></search-form>` is not processed, and the tag is rendered as plain text in the content area.

Since this is a tabset, the "child" doesn't need anything from the "parent", the search form and the tab itself have no scope dependencies. I tried playing with the link and compile functions after seeing some examples of nested structures, but can't seem tog et them to work.

How can I process the content of that variable so that element directives are rendered using their templates?

EDIT:

@sielakos Gave me exactly what I was hoping for, a reusable method for doing this.

I added a directive to my module called compile, which adds a wrapper to allow me to use plain text:

```
.directive("compile", function($compile){
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                link: function(scope, element, attr){
                    attr.$observe("compile", function(str){
                        var compiled = $compile("<div>"+str+"</div>")(scope);
                        jQuery(element).replaceWith(compiled);
                    })
                }
            }
        })
```

And I changed my tabset to use this directive:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="tab in tabset.tabs" ng-class="{active:tabset.current()==$index}">
            <a href ng-click="tabset.current($index)">{{tab}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div>
        <div ng-repeat="pane in tabset.panes">
            <div ng-show="tabset.current()==$index">
                <div compile="{{pane.contents}}"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is 'sidebar-tabset' element in your html markup?

Comment: i think it's because in sidebarTabset you are using this.panes = [{
                        contents : "<search-form></search-form>"
                    }, {
                        contents : "Favorite Pane"
                    }]; in the controller .. try putting it in a pre-link function

Comment: @ChrisHermut The code I provided is just the directives and template. the "sidebar-tabset" element is in the index.html, and as I said, it works as expected.

Comment: @MayK I'm not familiar with pre-link functions, but based on other examples I read, I couldn't find a way to use the link function to accomplish this because of the ng-repeat in the tabset

Comment: put it in the scope.panes first just to test if the problem really comes from here

Comment: It will not get compiled because you're adding your <search-form> markup in controller. Move it to compile function. It operates on template element. http://www.jvandemo.com/the-nitty-gritty-of-compile-and-link-functions-inside-angularjs-directives/

Comment: the controller and link functions don't have the same rendering time.. so it's possible that your directive don't get rendered for this reason

Comment: Tried setting a pre link function and adding the content via `scope.panes`, but now the `ng-repeat` doesn't work, should I be using `scope.panes` in the template as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to compile your string using [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) service if you wish to use it as you would use template. Otherwise it will be treated as normal string and displayed as it is.

Here is example how to use it inside directive:

```
var compiled = $compile(str)(scope);
element.empty();
element.append(compiled);
```

If you wish you can look at this fiddle for more complex example: 
https://jsfiddle.net/x78uuwp2/

Here I created simple compile directive that takes string compiles it and puts as element body with current scope.